# Magento base url static block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, base-url

I Have Cms Page I want to add contact us block withing it so I do as follows

```
<!– CONTACT FORM CODE BEGIN–>
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/~argentaustcom/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
<!– CONTACT FORM CODE END–>
```

but url not correct  so I Do As follows

```
<!– CONTACT FORM CODE BEGIN–>
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action={{store_url=""}}/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
<!– CONTACT FORM CODE END–>
```

but I echo block code instead of  echoing form
**this echo**

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action={{store_url=""}}/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

**not form**    I am trying to change "" to '' but not work

Comment: Try this: {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store url=''}}/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} , not sure what's the problem you are facing though.

Comment: yes i check not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**{{store url=""}** and **{{store direct_url=''}}** will not work in cms page within block tag.

**{{store url=""}** and **{{store direct_url=''}}** only convert to domain.com if it will put separately, Not within any tag. *in your case it is in block tag*

You need to put the block like following

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

OR

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="http://domain.com/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: i think  issue is {{store url=""} and {{store direct_url=''}} will not work in cms page within block tag. however i put url static url to solve it

Comment: yes. you can also use static url. i have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

OR

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```